# How to handle 1000+ images in a C# Application?

Tags: c#

A winform control for displaying a list of images is currently implemented with a flowlayoutpanel and a collection of pictureboxes.  But even at thumbnail scale (64x64) when we when start to approach 1000+ images we get OutOfMemory exceptions - our actual problem lies from the thumbnail generation part and the creation of the Image object.

I haven't been able to find any strategies from the existing image viewing examples on the net regarding a large number of images so does anybody have any links or strategies for solving this problem of displaying a list of 1000+ images?

As a starting point we really only need these image objects around when the thumbnail's picture box is in view.  Then we would only have 10 image objects created but is there a smarter way of doing this other than loading and destroying image objects?

Thanks,
Edward

Answer (score 5):

You should display only one screen of images at a time.

When the user drags the scrollbar, destroy those images and load new ones.

Comment: ...and have the control load the images in a separate thread so as not to cause lagginess when the user scrolls.

Comment: How do I know a picturebox is in view?  On the Scrollable panel there's ScrollIntoView function - what's the equivalent event?

Answer (score 0):

WPF handles this in a great way. If you have turned on Virtualization, the ListBox will create only the control that are visible to the screen.

In your case, keep reference to the images in a list. Put a pictureBox, and based on the Scrollbar, change the image on the pictureBox.

Comment: WPF won't help; the images themselves will still be loaded.

Comment: Nope. Using Virtualization and Lazy Load object will ensure the images not be loaded in the collection. 

There are lots of things happening with WPF and Virtualization and I think presentation framework is build to help on this matter.